# Bash while loop behaves differently when run remotely vs locally

Tags: bash, file, ssh

There is a simple log file /tmp/test.log

```
2019-12-09 15:28:12 UTC [6308] App1
2019-12-09 15:29:08 UTC [1246] App2
2019-12-09 15:30:57 UTC [5541] App3
```

There is a simple bash script /tmp/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < /tmp/test.log
```

If I run this script locally it works as expected:

```
$ /tmp/test.sh
2019-12-09 15:28:12 UTC [6308] App1
2019-12-09 15:29:08 UTC [1246] App2
2019-12-09 15:30:57 UTC [5541] App3
```

but if I run this script via ssh I'm getting something unexpected:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 "/tmp/test.sh"
2019-12-09 15:28:12 UTC 0 3 App1
2019-12-09 15:29:08 UTC 1 App2
2019-12-09 15:30:57 UTC 1 App3
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: looks like it is interpolating the array in the read line which is odd.

Comment: but why does this interpolation occur only via SSH?

Comment: use  `echo "$line"`

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine, maybe some execution has run? Try `bash -x` or some equivalent?

Comment: Do you use the same versions of Bash on local & remote machines?

Comment: As you can see I connect to 127.0.0.1, so the bash version is the same.

Comment: Using `echo "$line"` helped

Comment: Aside from special treatment by `echo`, your script essentially does a `cat /tmp/test.log`. So, if instead of doing the loop, you simply do the `cat` in your script, do you still see the differences in the output? How does /tmp/test.log look like when inspected with `xxd`?

Comment: Unquoted variables are subject to word splitting and **pathname expansion**. `touch 7; var="[12734]"; echo $var` will also output just `7`.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a couple of separate things interacting here to cause the
confusing result.  Here's my best guess explanation.

The value you have for the important IFS variable is probably  `20 09 0a` (these
are the  hex codes , for space, tab, newline).  This has important consequences
on the `echo` (and also `read` statements).  (use `echo  -n "$IFS" | hexdump` to see values).

The `read` command will read each line from the file, and add them all into the
`line` variable.  It will actually tokenise each line, and add each word to
`line`.

The `echo` statement will cause evaluation of the value in `line`.  The shell
will use `IFS` to separate the value into separate tokens, and then pass them all
to echo, which will print them, separated by spaces.  I.e., there is a shell
pre-processing step that is hard to observe.

The problem arises for tokens like `[6308]` etc.  The square brackets are used
for shell globbing, so when bash encounters something like `[6308]` it will try
to match it to files in the current directory named like `6` or `3` or `0` or
`8`.  So if you have two files named `0` and `3`, it will match them both and
return the string `0 3`.

The reason you have different results when run locally as opposed to via ssh is
likely just due to the current working directory in which the script is
invoked. When run via ssh, it won't run from the your local current directory.  To find the cwd used for the ssh invocation, just put a `pwd` near
the top of your file.  I'm guessing that the directory used via the ssh invocation has files named like `0` etc.

The simple fix is to prevent the shell processing the contents of `$line`, by
enclosing it with quotes, as in  `echo "$line"` . You could also adjust IFS, but quoting the string is usual practice.